# select in column that has array(value1,value2,…) in sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table called "users"

inside this table a column named "Cities" has array in it (1,2, 3,...)

row1 :"1,2,15,69,98"

row2 :"7,9,15,5,69"

row3 :"7,3,1,5,6"

how can I select rows which has multiple value in same time

for exp : I want to select rows which has 1 in it

the result should display row1 and row3 .

Comment: Hi please provide your table structure and desired result

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a column is very bad idea. Consider changing your table design

Comment: @Prdp thank you for this comment . but i not create this tables . i just can using this table .

Comment: @JimMacaulay I think it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', Cities) > 0
```

As others have mentioned, storing CSV data in your `users` table is sub-optimal because it undermines much of the relational power which the database has.  But if you have to proceed as is, `FIND_IN_SET` might let you do that.

Answer (score 2):

you can refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE INSTR(cities, '1',1)>0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is possible, I will strongly recommend to store single value in a column.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
where Concat(',',col,',') like '%,1,%'
```

Between for another approach I posted this answer using `LIKE`. But Tim's `FIND_IN_SET` is a better approach here

Answer (score 1):

I think simply It should work for your requirement:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE Cities LIKE '%1,%'
```

Comment: this sql better for search . i have select this .